# Document.load() fails: System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not {

Tags: apex, failing-tests, xml, httpcalloutmock

I am getting the following error when tying to use the Document.load() method for my xml:

> ```
> System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1)
> ```
>
> Appuntamento.calloutBody: line 66, column 1

Here's the method that fails:

```
public static Map<String,Object> calloutBody(String jsonString,String endPoint,String codiceFlusso, String csId) {
    Log__c logObj=new Log__c();
    Map<String,Object> data=new Map<String,Object>();
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endPoint);//test endpoint
    //request.setEndpoint('https://hookb.in/OeMV18JxzEcnzzlkQmN9');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    request.setTimeout(120000);
    request.setBody(jsonString);
    System.debug('body richiesta: '+jsonString);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    System.debug('response status code: '+response.getStatusCode()+' | '+response.getStatus());
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) { 
        logObj.ApexClassName__c='Appuntamento.cls';
        logObj.Endpoint__c=request.getEndpoint();
        logObj.RequestBody__c=request.getBody();
        logObj.Status__c='Failed';
        logObj.RecordId__c = csId;
        logObj.Message__c='Errore invio callout';
        logObj.StackTrace__c='STATUS CODE: ' +response.getStatusCode() + ' | STATUS:' + response.getStatus();
    }else{
        logObj.ApexClassName__c='Appuntamento.cls';
        logObj.Endpoint__c=request.getEndpoint();
        logObj.RequestBody__c=request.getBody();
        logObj.RecordId__c = csId;
        logObj.Status__c='Submitted';
        logObj.Message__c='Invio callout avvenuto con successo!';
        logObj.StackTrace__c='STATUS CODE: ' +response.getStatusCode() + ' | STATUS:' + response.getStatus();
        String retXml=response.getBody().unescapeHtml4();
        retXml=retXml.remove('<root>');
        retXml=retXml.remove('</root>');
        System.debug('retXML: '+retXml);
        DOM.Document doc=new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(retXml);
        data=responseParserMaster(doc,codiceFlusso);
    }
    try {
        insert logObj;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('EXCEPTION CATCHED Appuntamento: '+e.getMessage()+' | StackTrace: '+e.getStackTraceString());
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is my test class and method:

```
@isTest
global class AppuntamentoTst implements HttpCalloutMock {
        global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
            HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.setBody('{"test": {"id":134345465, "name":"test"}}');
            response.setStatusCode(200);
            return response;
        }

@isTest
public static void confirmAppuntamentoTst(){
    Case cs = new Case();
    cs.RecordTypeId = '0121l0000009b2ZAAQ'; // allaccio metano recordType
    cs.CodicePraticaDistributore__c = 'codiceTest';
    insert cs;
    String inpputString = '2017-02-05T01:44:00.000Z';
    DateTime resultDateTime = DateTime.ValueofGmt(inpputString.replace('T', ' ')); 
    Map<String,Object> data = new Map<String,Object>{
        'csId' => cs.Id,
        'codFlusso' => '0170',
        'day' => resultDateTime,
        'day' => '2017-02-05',
        'range' => '44:00/44:00',
        'codiceAppuntamento' => '123445',
        'esito_app' => '1'
    };
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AppuntamentoTst());
    Test.startTest();
        Appuntamento.confirmAppuntamento(data);
    Test.stopTest();
    Log__c lg = [SELECT Id FROM Log__c LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals(true, lg != null);
}
```

The 3 debugs I have print the following:

> 17:04:32:625 USER_DEBUG [42]|DEBUG|body richiesta: <cod_prat_utente>00335632</cod_prat_utente><cod_prat_distr>distr</cod_prat_distr><codice_appuntamento>app</codice_appuntamento><esito_conferma>OK</esito_conferma>
>
> 17:04:32:625 USER_DEBUG [44]|DEBUG|response status code: 200 | null
>
> 17:04:32:629 USER_DEBUG [64]|DEBUG|retXML: {"test": {"id":134345465,
> "name":"test"}}

I'm not sure why it is failing. Isn't the load() method supposed to work this way?

Comment: The response from Mock is returning JSON representation whereas in your line `String retXml=response.getBody().unescapeHtml4();` you are expecting XML. Is that correct?

Comment: @manijt5190 yes, that was it. By changing the String in the response mock everything worked fine.
Thanks!